# How to ORDER BY Alphanumeric values in SQL specific columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

```
create table Employee(id int, Registration_no varchar(50),Name varchar(50))

insert into @Employee values(1,'DLW/TTC/19/3','RAMESH')
insert into @Employee values(2,'DLW/TTC/19/2','RAJEEV')
insert into @Employee values(3,'DLW/TTC/19/1','RUPAK')
insert into @Employee values(4,'DLW/TTC/19/4','RAMLAAL')
insert into @Employee values(5,'DLW/TTC/19/8','RITESH')
insert into @Employee values(6,'DLW/TTC/19/6','HRITIK')
insert into @Employee values(7,'DLW/TTC/19/9','ROSHAN')
insert into @Employee values(8,'DLW/TTC/19/7','RUPALI')
insert into @Employee values(9,'DLW/TTC/19/5','SHRISTI')
insert into @Employee values(10,'DLW/TTC/19/10','ROSHNI')

select * from Employee
```

Hello I have the table given above.
Actually am facing problem while am trying to order this table's column (Registration_no) 
So kindly help me to ORDER it according to its (Registration_no) column

Its not matter that how the other columns are arranged. I just want my Registration_no column to be arranged in the specific order like this

```
Registration_no
DLW/TTC/19/1
DLW/TTC/19/2
DLW/TTC/19/3
DLW/TTC/19/4
DLW/TTC/19/5
DLW/TTC/19/6
DLW/TTC/19/7
DLW/TTC/19/8
DLW/TTC/19/9
DLW/TTC/19/10
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: `select * from Employee order by registration_no`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan am using ms sql

Comment: @TheImpaler i had done it but its not working

Comment: Would storing number as /01 instead of /1 help order it the way you want it?

Comment: "it's not working" -- Wrong result or do you get an error? What error?

Comment: @harsh define "it is not working"

Comment: I suppose OP is looking to have /2 value above /10. I dont think the query can be wrong as such.

Comment: @TheImpaler i dont get any error it executed but the result is not correct it prints the result in this order               1   -10-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9

Comment: @shahkalpesh i know this but the question is i have to do it like this so what to do

Comment: @SalmanA its not working means its not giving the correct output as i want      it prints it like this 1-10-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9  but i want to print the result serially

Comment: @HarshSharma - Of course it's correct... if you're treating the number as a string, instead of a number.  You have to convert it (back) into a number to get it to sort the way you want, or prefix with a number of zeros.  It _looks_ like that column is a multi-part key of some sort - would it be better to split it into multiple columns, and order based on that?

Comment: `1-10-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9` is correct, since these are NOT numbers, but `VARCHAR`. If you want to order it as numeric, you'll need to create (or compute on the fly) a column of numeric value.

Comment: @harsh what about the other components (especially 19)? Do you want it sorted, too?

Comment: @SalmanA yeah i want the whole Registraion_no column show me the result fully like this. - > DLW/TTC/19/1 - > DLW/TTC/19/2 - > DLW/TTC/19/3......DLW/TTC/19/10  i want my output like this

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse some of first portions in the column Registration_no is same so we can neglect it or skip it and then we can arrange it in order, i think for this we have to assume two sections like AlphaSection & NumericSection  i dont know how to do it coz i dont know more about SQL am a fresher maybe u guys do something so please help me to figure out this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reverse` function together with `charindex` function

```
SELECT e.*, cast( reverse(substring(reverse(Registration_no),1,
             charindex('/',reverse(Registration_no),1) -1 ) ) as int ) as nr
  FROM employee e
 ORDER BY nr;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/KJB66592)</kbd>

*The main principle is extracting the pieces and converting them to a numerical value, such as integer, in the tail part of the string values. It's easier to operate from the beginning with [`substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to this extraction provided [`reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function is used to make read the string reversely. And in this case we need to determine the position of the first delimiter(`/`) by contribution of [`charindex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. All those functions exist since the version 2008.*

Comment: can you please explain me this answer because am a beginner and i dont know about more functions and there working. please explain me or give me any link where from i can able to understand these above codes properly.....Thanks.

Comment: @HarshSharma Hi Harsh, I added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This will sort by the digits to the right of the last `/` in the `Registration_No` string. I'm only including the `SortColumn` in the result set so you can see the values. You can omit it from your query.

```
SELECT 
  e.*,
  CAST(RIGHT(e.Registration_no,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(e.Registration_no))-1) AS INTEGER) AS SortColumn
FROM @Employee AS e
ORDER BY
  CAST(RIGHT(e.Registration_no,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(e.Registration_no))-1) AS INTEGER)
```

Results:

```
+----+-----------------+---------+------------+
| id | Registration_no |  Name   | SortColumn |
+----+-----------------+---------+------------+
|  3 | DLW/TTC/19/1    | RUPAK   |          1 |
|  2 | DLW/TTC/19/2    | RAJEEV  |          2 |
|  1 | DLW/TTC/19/3    | RAMESH  |          3 |
|  4 | DLW/TTC/19/4    | RAMLAAL |          4 |
|  9 | DLW/TTC/19/5    | SHRISTI |          5 |
|  6 | DLW/TTC/19/6    | HRITIK  |          6 |
|  8 | DLW/TTC/19/7    | RUPALI  |          7 |
|  5 | DLW/TTC/19/8    | RITESH  |          8 |
|  7 | DLW/TTC/19/9    | ROSHAN  |          9 |
| 10 | DLW/TTC/19/10   | ROSHNI  |         10 |
+----+-----------------+---------+------------+
```

The `SortColumn` functions first `REVERSE` the string, then use `CHARINDEX` to find the position from the end of the string of the last occurrence of `/`, then take that number -1 from the right side of the original column (-1 to exclude the `/` itself).

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer. If this code helped solve your problem, please take a moment to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It lets other users know the question has an answer, and rewards the user who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Comment: Okay sir i'll do it

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern at the end of Registration_no is always like `/X` or `/XX` then:

```
select * from Employee
order by 
  case left(right(Registration_no, 2), 1) 
    when '/' then 
      left(Registration_no, len(Registration_no) - 1) + '0' + right(Registration_no, 1)
    else Registration_no
  end
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f920d28cf965f648c604e175ebc894c).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'll notice as you try to order by the Registration_no is that it will be ordered alphabetically due to the nature of the string contents of the column of type varchar. So the correct way to do it is to convert the last two parts of the reg no into numbers and use them in an order by clause. (in this case we can use only the last part since the 2nd last is always 19)

Doing a bit of search I found this function 'Parsename' which has a usage in replication scenarios as it splits the SQL object schema name into its forming parts, so we can use it here (as long as the reg no parts doesn't exceed 4 parts "the SQL objects maximum parts")

So this will work in that case in SQL Server (T-SQL):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee 
order by cast(Parsename(replace(Registration_no,'/','.'),1) as int)
```

[More info here](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/using-the-parsename-function-to-split-delimited-data)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although I dont like the way the number is extracted, this is how it can be done

```
select cast(substring(registration_no, charindex('/', registration_no, len(registration_no) -3) + 1, 3) as int), 
    * from Employee 
    order by 1
```

I would suggest you order it on the frontend using regex assuming that you are wanting to order it for display purpose.

Comment: Yeah i want to order it for displaying purpose

Comment: @HarshSharma what if you `registration_no` column has values such as `DLW/TTC/19/10101`, `DLW/TTC/19/2010` ...

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
select *
from Employee
order  by LEFT(Registration_no,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Registration_no)-1)-- alpha sort
, CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Registration_no,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Registration_no),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Registration_no)),'/', '')) -- number sort
```

Comment: I had done this its not giving the correct output  before posting this question here i search it on google and i got this answer on a website and i tried it on my machine but its not resulting the correct output it just works as an usual ORDER BY works

Answer (score -1):

Try this query.

> ```
> create table #Employee(id int, Registration_no varchar(50),Name varchar(50))
>
> insert into #Employee values(1,'DLW/TTC/19/3','RAMESH')
> insert into #Employee values(2,'DLW/TTC/19/2','RAJEEV')
> insert into #Employee values(3,'DLW/TTC/19/1','RUPAK')
> insert into #Employee values(4,'DLW/TTC/19/4','RAMLAAL')
> insert into #Employee values(5,'DLW/TTC/19/8','RITESH')
> insert into #Employee values(6,'DLW/TTC/19/6','HRITIK')
> insert into #Employee values(7,'DLW/TTC/19/9','ROSHAN')
> insert into #Employee values(8,'DLW/TTC/19/7','RUPALI')
> insert into #Employee values(9,'DLW/TTC/19/5','SHRISTI')
> insert into #Employee values(10,'DLW/TTC/19/10','ROSHNI')
>
>
> select * from #Employee
> order by Registration_no
> ```

```
id          Registration_no                                    Name
----------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
3           DLW/TTC/19/1                                       RUPAK
10          DLW/TTC/19/10                                      ROSHNI
2           DLW/TTC/19/2                                       RAJEEV
1           DLW/TTC/19/3                                       RAMESH
4           DLW/TTC/19/4                                       RAMLAAL
9           DLW/TTC/19/5                                       SHRISTI
6           DLW/TTC/19/6                                       HRITIK
8           DLW/TTC/19/7                                       RUPALI
5           DLW/TTC/19/8                                       RITESH
7           DLW/TTC/19/9                                       ROSHAN
```

Comment: This clearly doesn't answer the OP's question. Please see the comments and either edit the answer to address the question or delete the answer.

Comment: @EricBrandt yeah its not the answer that i want its not like that i also did this but its not the result i want

Comment: did u tried the query i pasted here? if yes , can u please tell ,what is wrong about outpur?  above query will divide resgistration no into two parts. eg: it will divide 'DLW/TTC/19/1' into ''DLW/TTC/'  and 191 and then sort output by alpha part first  then it will sort by the number part..